# C Programming compiler error: Radius input: output error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, output

um... I have a  question about 'C programming compiler error'.

I even defined the PI and entered the correct input,
 but I do not know what is the problem.

 Typing it with a decimal point does not fix the problem. 
 I would appreciate it if you let me know the problem.

this  is  my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.141592

int main(void)
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", a*a*PI);
    printf("%d\n", 2*PI*a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error? You are printing floating point numbers as integers, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake could be that, if you want to print decimal number to the screen, you could use `printf("%f\n",a*a*PI)` not `printf("%d\n", a*a*PI);`